# BackButtonStyle (Part of StandardStyles.xaml in metro app) causes other elements to be disabled

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have used `BackButtonStyle` which is created in `StandardStyles.xaml` (while creating new metro project).

Problem is that it disables other controls. Button, and Slider are disabled and cannot be invoked.

When i remove the BackButtonStyle, the other Button/Slider works as normal.

```
      <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!--Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}"-->
        <Button x:Name="backButton" Click="GoBack" Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}"   Margin="10"  >Back</Button>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Application settings" Foreground="White" FontSize="24" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10"/>
      </Grid>
      <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">

      <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" FontSize="14"  Text="Toast Notification Interval (minutes)  " Margin="10"/>
        <Slider  Grid.Row="2"  x:Name="NotificationIntervalSlider"  Minimum="1" Maximum="10"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" FontSize="14" x:Name="lblIntervalInfo"  Margin="10"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="4">Text</Button>
```

BackButtonStyle is below (it is large, provided by default)

```
     <Style x:Key="BackButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="48"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="48"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="36,0,36,36"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI Symbol"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="56"/>
    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="BackButton"/>
    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="Back"/>
    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.ItemType" Value="Navigation Button"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid">
                    <Grid Margin="-1,-16,0,0">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="BackgroundGlyph" Text="&#xE0A8;" Foreground="{StaticResource BackButtonBackgroundBrush}"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="NormalGlyph" Text="{StaticResource BackButtonGlyph}" Foreground="{StaticResource BackButtonGlyphBrush}"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="ArrowGlyph" Text="&#xE0A6;" Foreground="{StaticResource BackButtonPressedGlyphBrush}" Opacity="0"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Rectangle
                        x:Name="FocusVisualWhite"
                        IsHitTestVisible="False"
                        Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeBrush}"
                        StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                        StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                        Opacity="0"
                        StrokeDashOffset="1.5"/>
                    <Rectangle
                        x:Name="FocusVisualBlack"
                        IsHitTestVisible="False"
                        Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeBrush}"
                        StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                        StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                        Opacity="0"
                        StrokeDashOffset="0.5"/>

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource BackButtonHoverBackgroundBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource BackButtonHoverGlyphBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource BackButtonGlyphBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="ArrowGlyph"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                        To="1"
                                        Duration="0"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="NormalGlyph"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                        To="0"
                                        Duration="0"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhite"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                        To="1"
                                        Duration="0"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                        To="1"
                                        Duration="0"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I can see some `IsHitTestVisible=false`, which i have manually removed and tested, and then also same result.

Comment: Is this in the settings charm? What is the definition of the grid that it all is in? Does it have two row definitions?

Comment: Yes it is simulated to be in settings charm.
I followed http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2011/09/28/lighting-up-your-c-metro-apps-by-using-the-settings-contract.aspx . As per my understanding, the UI is part of main app, and is shown/hidden (by manipulating Margin), on events from Settings Charm.
Thus it appears as if part of settings charm, but actually it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try getting rid of the Margin and Content here:

```
<Button x:Name="backButton" Click="GoBack" Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}"   Margin="10"  >Back</Button>
```

To make it

```
<Button
    Click="GoBack"
    Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}" />
```

Comment: That can be done for the  sake of brevity. But it is unrelated from original question.